# Start new navigation without exiting from previous navigation in Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, navigation

I'm starting **Google Map** from my application to **Navigate** the user to some location.

Here is my **code**.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" + rideDetailsModel.getEndLatitude() + "," + rideDetailsModel.getEndLongtitude()));
        startActivity(intent);
```

I'm using **Chat Head** like Uber driver app to take back to my application from **Google Map**. That's working fine. The problem is, While I'm invoking the same code above, Google Map asks me to exit from the previous navigation. Because previous navigation is not cleared.

How to force **Google Map** to create new navigation without asking to close the previous one.

Two methods can solve my problem.

**Method 1**

If I can close Google map application from my application, my problem solved. But I searched a lot, the **non-rooted** phone can't kill other applications.

**Method 2**

Clear the previous navigation and create new navigation. So **Google Map** won't ask the user to exit from the previous navigation before start the new navigation.

Comment: I would be disappointed if it turns out there is a way to do that, because as a user I certainly won't be happy if my current/previous navigation route would be removed without my approval.

Comment: Consider you are a uber driver. For each ride you have to manually exit from previous navigation to star new navigation.@azizbekian

Comment: I understand your use case, it makes sense. But if google would give such an API to interact with Google Maps app, then developers would misuse that in their favor, which would make user suffer. That's the point of my previous comment.

Comment: Good point. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I got a new info. In uber driver app, my exact requirement is there. How Uber made it possible. Do you have any idea. @azizbekian

Comment: rather than opening up an implicit intent, create a custom map and open up an explicit intent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Method 3** : (Make it simply by clearing the intent flags)

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```